# Is there a way to set up an SSH connection (pass-wordless login) between host A and host B while running playbook from hostC using ansible only?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to set up a passwordless login (copy id_rsa.pub from server A to server B) from server A to server B while running a playbook from controller machine C. The playbook:

1. cannot have an inventory file. The host IP will be passed from the command line to the playbook as:

> ansible-playbook -i , test.yml

2. Server A DNS name or IP address will be hardcoded in my playbook.

I have tried:

1. Using fetch module, I tried fetching ssh key(id_rsa_serverA.pub) from server A to controller C and then using copy module to copy the ssh_key(id_rsa_ServerA) to Server B. While it did the work, it does not adhere to the project guidelines I am working on.
2. Tried 'synchronize' module with ansible 2.5. Fails.

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar thing,

i use `user` module on serverA with option `generate_ssh_key: yes` and user `register: user_pubkey`

then i use `authorized_key` module with delegate_to `serverB`, setting the key to `"{{ user_pubkey.stdout }}" for the needed`user:`

you can pass @IP of serverB as extra_vers at launch time : `ansible-playbook ... ... ... -e serverB=serverB_@IP`

hope this helps

cheers